# id элементов в Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, activity

Я не могу до конца разобраться, id элементов в Activity должно быть уникальным для всего проекта или только для одного Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для примера можно посмотреть в [доки](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#id):

> Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely
> identify the View within the tree. When the app is compiled, this ID
> is referenced as an integer, but the ID is typically assigned in the
> layout XML file as a string, in the id attribute.

---

> Любой объект представления может иметь связанный с ним целочисленный
> идентификатор, чтобы однозначно идентифицировать представление в
> дереве. При компиляции приложения на этот идентификатор ссылаются как
> на целое число, но идентификатор обычно назначается в XML-файле макета
> в виде строки в атрибуте id.

то есть можно использовать id одинаковыми, главное чтобы они были доступны в контексте макета xml. Проще всего это можно увидеть когда вы получаете ошибку об обращении к несуществующему элементу. Уникальность должна сохраняться только внутри файла разметки, в противном случае у вас будет ошибка при компиляции.

Answer (score 1):

id элементов в Activity должно быть уникальным для одного Activity